# No consigo Pintar celda datatable php

Tags: javascript, php, css

Estoy intentando pintar celdas de datatable cuando se cumple una condición que es cuando falte 1 día para que venza el pago el tr completo se coloree en rojo de otra forma no suceda nada, pero no estoy pudiendo

Lo que hice aca es el sistema de vencimiento y un contador para que cada tr que se genere tenga su propio id ej estado1, estado2, estado3, etc.

```
<tbody>
                            <?php
                            
                            $student = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM student order by name asc ");
                            $fecha_hoy= date("Y-m-d");
                            function calcular_dias($fecha_hoy, $vencimiento){
                            $diferencia_dias=(strtotime($fecha_hoy)-strtotime($vencimiento))/86400; 
                            $diferencia_dias=abs($diferencia_dias); 
                            $diferencia_dias=floor($diferencia_dias); 
                            return $diferencia_dias;
                            }
                            $i = 0; //contador 
                            while ($row = $student->fetch_assoc()){
                                $fecha_hasta=$row['vencimiento']; 
                                $diferencia_dias= calcular_dias($fecha_hoy, $fecha_hasta); 
                                $unico= 'estado' .$i;//generador de id para cada estudiante o cliente y poder pintar si se cumple la condiciones
                                $i++;
                                ?>
                                <tr id="<?php echo $unico;?>"> //lo imprimo acá

                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <?php echo $i++ ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $row['id_no'] ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo ucwords($row['name']) ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>Fecha de vencimiento: </p>
                                        <?php echo $row['vencimiento'] ?>
                                        <p>Faltan  
                                        <input class="" value="<?php echo $diferencia_dias; ?>" type="button" name="contador" id="vence"> dias</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
```

y mi js es este

```
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].value=== 1 && inputs[i].id=='vence'){
        <?php echo $unico;?>.style.backgroundColor = "#b61800"; //intento colorear de rojo el tr completo
        <?php echo $unico;?>.style.color = "#fff";
        }
    if (inputs[i].value >= 2 && inputs[i].value <= 5  && inputs[i].id=='vence'){
            inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "#edd900";
            inputs[i].style.color = "#000";
        }
    if (inputs[i].value >= 6 && inputs[i].id==='vence'){
        inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "#059d05";
        inputs[i].style.color = "#fff";
        }
    
}
```

En fin lo unico que hace es pintarme 1 solo tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a ofrecer dos soluciones, una simplificando la tarea con SQL y otra modificando tu Javascript.

**Con SQL y PHP**

Si comparas las fechas directamente en la sentencia SQL te ahorrarás usar el código Javascript y necesitarás mucho menos código PHP.

Añade una columna a tu consulta SQL restando la fecha de mañana a la del vencimiento, tal que así:

```
vencimiento - CURDATE() AS expiring
```

De este modo, se añadirá un columna llamada `expiring` a tu consulta y la podrás usar directamente en tu código PHP para dibujar cada fila de un color u otro en función de la diferencia de días :

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
    
    $student = $conn->query("SELECT *, vencimiento - CURDATE() AS expiring FROM student ORDER BY name ASC");
    $i       = 1;

    while ($row = $student->fetch_assoc()) {
    
        // Valores por defecto, que cambiaremos en función de si se cumple una de las condiciones de más abajo
        $text       = 'Falta(n) ' . $row['expiring'] . ' día(s).';
        $background = '#fff';
        $color      = '#000';
    
        if ($row['expiring'] == 0) { // Vence hoy
            $text       = 'Vence hoy';
            $background = '#b61800';
            $color      = '#fff';
        } elseif ($row['expiring'] == 1) { // Vence mañana
            $text       = 'Vence mañana';
            $background = '#b61800';
            $color      = '#fff';
        } elseif ($row['expiring'] > 1 && $row['expiring'] < 7) { // Vence en una semana
            $background = '#edd900';
        } elseif ($row['expiring'] < 0) { // Vencido
            $text       = 'Vencido';
        }
        
    ?>
    <tr style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>; background: <?php echo $background; ?>;">
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['id_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords($row['name']); ?></td>
        <td>
            <p>Fecha de vencimiento: <?php echo $row['vencimiento']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

**Con tu Javascript**

Si lo que quieres es seguir usando Javascript, las correcciones que haría son las siguientes:

Lo primero, para lo que quieres hacer es más interesante guardar el valor con la diferencia de días en otro tipo de elemento que no sea un botón, tal vez lo mejor sea usar un `span` o un campo tipo `hidden`. Además, el atributo `id` debe ser único para cada elemento que incluyas en HTML, no debería haber varios elementos (botones en tu caso) con el mismo.

Luego, dentro del `for` estás utilizando distintos `if` que puedes encadenar con `else`, para que así no haga obligatoriamente una comprobación en los tres casos, si es que uno de los primeros ya se ha cumplido.

También, el utilizar `getElementsByTagName()` puede ser problemático porque tal y como lo tienes declarado, haría la comprobación y aplicaría el cambio de estilos sobre cualquier campo `input`, incluidos aquellos que no estuviesen en la tabla. Además, eso te hace incluir la condición `inputs[i].id == 'vence'` en cada `if`, cosa que puedes solventar si utilizas `querySelectorAll()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y le asignas una clase a los elementos que quieras pasar por el `for`.

Por último, estás intentando aplicar los estilos sobre el botón, no sobre la fila. Para eso necesitas hacer los cambios sobre la etiqueta `tr`, cosa que puedes hacer usando `closest()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

```js
var diferencias = document.querySelectorAll('.diferencia');

for (i=0; i < diferencias.length; i++) {
    var value = diferencias[i].innerHTML; // o diferencias[i].value si utilizases un campo tipo hidden en lugar de span
    var tr    = diferencias[i].closest('tr'); // la columna en la que está incluido el elemento
    
    if (value == 1) {
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#b61800";
        tr.style.color = "#fff";
    } else if (value >= 2 && value <= 5) {
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#edd900";
        tr.style.color = "#000";
    } else if (value >= 6) {
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#059d05";
        tr.style.color = "#fff";
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Falta(n) <span class="diferencia">1</span> día(s).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Falta(n) <span class="diferencia">2</span> día(s).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Falta(n) <span class="diferencia">1</span> día(s).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Falta(n) <span class="diferencia">8</span> día(s).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Falta(n) <span class="diferencia">4</span> día(s).</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono de las 2 formas, es mi primera preg y me dio mucha ilusion saber que hay una comunidad tan fuerte aca, gracias!!!